# Facebook Server-Side API - push custom events to create Custom Audience

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

We try to use Server-Side API to push custom events to our pixel in order to create event-based Custom Audiences in Facebook Ads (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/server-side-api/)

We use _fbp cookie value to match users (it's a first party cookie created on our website by FB pixel).

For example (Python):

```py
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adspixel import AdsPixel

my_app_id = 'X'
my_app_secret = 'X'
my_access_token = 'X'
my_pixel_id = 'X'

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=my_access_token, app_id=my_app_id, app_secret=my_app_secret)

fields = []
params = {
    'data': [{'event_name': 'icrm_test_20191113_fbp_1m', 'event_time': 1573230217, 'user_data':{'fbp': 'fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397'}}]
}

print(AdsPixel(my_pixel_id).create_event(fields=fields, params=params))
```

The problem is, when we create a Custom Audience in Facebook Ads, the size of the list is always < 1000, even if we push hundreds of thousands of cookie IDs, which means Facebook matched a very low % of cookies, which were sent.

Custom Audience definition based on server-side event:

[image: Custom Audience definition based on server-side event]

List size is always <1000, no matter how many fbp cookies are sent:

[image: List size is always <1000, no matter how many fbp cookies are sent]

It seems like there is some kind of an issue matching _fbp cookies to Facebook user profiles. Is there any known way of improving/fixing matching results? We can't use hashes of sensitive data.

External_id matching (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/server-side-api/parameters) also gave us similar results.

Answer (score 0):

The event time you are using there translates to 11/08/2019 @ 4:23pm (UTC).
So they're not gonna get included in your 30 day window.

Try importing time

```
import time
```

Then set

```
'event_time': int(time.time())
```